# VS 2015 TestMethod The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, http-error

I'm getting the below error when I try to run TestMethod through VS Test explorer (both Pro and Ent editions with Update3) step that calls an external service (attaches certificate). However if I run the same TestMethod using Resharper command (unit test session) it succeeds. It's successful, if I host the application too. The library that calls the external service works fine in another VS 2015 solution.

*System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.*

I'm not able to find, what the difference could be between VS 2015 test runner and Resharper's test runner that's resulting in this error. Any pointers/solutions?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Currently the .Net framework used is 4.6.1, but if I switch to .Net framework 4.5.2 for all the projects, the call to external service is successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution was to add below statement in the method where I make the http call.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

VSTest runner seems to be using the default Tls12, which was not configured on server and hence the error.